# Not able to fetch data after refreshing dynamically created url in angular js application

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and this my first post to stackoverflow. Iam trying to create small part of existing angular. 
Iam trying to fetch dynamic url for "allproducts" page where url will have /allproducts/{corresponding city id} 
My App.js looks like this:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/',
{
    templateUrl: "view"
})
.when('/Cities',
 {
    templateUrl: "cities"
})
.when('/products',
{
    templateUrl: "view/cities_products"
})
.when('/allproducts/:id',
{
    templateUrl: "city/{id}/products"
})
.otherwise({
    template: 'NOT FOUND'
})
});
```

and rest is defined inside a controller. This is to get city data

```
httpService.get(get_data_url3,"")
.then(function (result) {
 if (result.status == 200) {
  $scope.cities_data=result.data.data;
  console.log($scope.cities_data);
  }
 if (result.status == 404) {
  console.log("unauthorised");
 }
}, function (status) {
console.log(status);
});
```

This is to get product data on click of corresponding city

```
$scope.allCityProducts = function(city,path)
{
 $location.path('/allproducts/'+city.id);
 var get_products_url=initial_url+"products/"+city.id;
 $scope.selected_city=city;
 httpService.get(get_products_url,"")
 .then(function (result) {
   if (result.status == 200) {
    $scope.product_data=result.data;
   }
   if (result.status == 404) {
     console.log("unauthorised");
   }
 }, function (status) {
   console.log(status);
 });
}
```

And html code for cities is below on whose click dynamic product url is being fetchd

```
<div class="view_context">
<br>
<div class="row table-heading">
  <div class="column medium-4">Cities <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></div>
  <div class="column medium-4">View Products <i class="fa fa-star"></i></div>
  <div class="column medium-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="table-inside column medium-12" ng-repeat="city in cities_data">
  <div class="column medium-4"> {{city.city_name}}</div>
  <div class="column medium-4"><a style="color:black;" ng-click="allCityProducts(city,path)"><i class="fa fa-share-square" style="margin-right:10px"></i>VIEW</a></div>
  <div class="column medium-4"></div>   
</div>
```

and the product page is below

```
<div class="table-inside table-white column medium-12">
    <div class="column medium-4">{{prod.product_name}}</div>
    <div class="column medium-3">{{prod.product_price_city | currency:"&#8377; "}}</div> 
    <div class="column medium-3"><a style="color:black;" data-reveal-id="productModal" ng-click="editproduct(prod)"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i> VIEW/EDIT</a></div>
    <div class="column medium-2"><i class="fa fa-trash" ng-click="deleteproduct(prod,selected_city.id,$index)"></i></div>
  </div>
```

All works well except when dynamically created product page is reloaded no data is being fetched because httpservice is working on ng-click="allcityproducts". where city id is passed. What can be done to sort this??

Answer (score 0):

For fetching a template based on the city id ,you could have `templateUrl` function instead of using URL string directly. templateUrl function will have 1st parameter(here its `params`) which will have route parameter object.

**Code**

```
templateUrl: function(params){
   return "city/"+ params.id +"/products"
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your efforts, but i wasn't able to figure it out. i found a way out by using 'window.location.hash.split("/")[2]' to fetch current url's city id and set it to fetch data through httpservice

Comment: Yeah i tried using function as you mentioned and passed city as parameter. It didn't work. Might be issue with param passed. hence changed templateUrl to city/products. Sorry if i didn't understood it well am new to angular